# Gradle Project declares a dependency from configuration 'detachedConfiguration1' to configuration 'default'

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/f5428f52afa36c5f2719d047ccc53213 and run it with "./gradlew build" with following error:

```
└─$ ./gradlew build
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :
ArtifactoryUser user: null
Using Java from /home/katya/java (version 11.0.2)
Detected development environment
[buildinfo] Properties file path was not found! (Relevant only for builds running on a CI Server)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/katya/tmp_work/groovy/gradle/binarycompatibility.gradle' line: 67

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':groovy-console:japicmp'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':groovy-console:detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-console:2.4.16.
     Required by:
         project :groovy-console
      > Project :groovy-console declares a dependency from configuration 'detachedConfiguration1' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :groovy-console.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

Could you explain what is going on? What is 'detachedConfiguratoin1' and how to fix this error?

Comment: Are you trying to build Groovy 2.4 from source?

Comment: @thokuest Groovy 2.5.8 from source